# What are the good practices and useful design pattern to provide an API which supports internationalization?

Tags: internationalization, api-design

Given an existing API working well with the usual mono-locale approach, what are the steps one should follow to turn it into an internationalized version, which enable user to send/receive keys/values in localized versions?

End user interface internationalization is a well covered topic.internationalized. But how can it be pushed further on request and response? If someone hits an API and wants the response in German how can I do so ?

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of tricky answering without any kind of context, or sample API, or a even a high-level description of what your API does.

But in general it is best to separate your APIs into several layers.
The core functionality and data at the application level should be locale independent, something like this http://mihai-nita.net/2005/10/25/data-internationalization/

Then you would have the presentation layers, with things like date/time/number formatters, collation, localization, etc.